# Excel VLOOKUP Increment

Tags: excel, increment, vlookup

I am creating a excel file that will pull a daily report from a folder on a different drive everyday. I was wondering if there is a way to increment a file name in the formula by 1 easily?

The formula I am currently using is:

```
=VLOOKUP("Oil Production(Sm³)",'G:\DPNA\Non_Op_Assets\Hib\Pe\Production\Reports\Daily Report\2019\01 Jan19\[190113 Daily Report.xls]Daily Report'!$A$1:$P$500,3,FALSE)*1
```

I was wondering If it is possible to be able to get the 190113 to increment by one for the next 365 cells easily.

Comment: Is that possible to do where the number is in the file lookup directory?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily. It looks to me that not only do you need to increment the 190113, but it will need to flip over to 190201 for the 1st February, and also the file path has the year and the month spelled out.

This can be constructed with formulas, though. You can create the formulas that generate the path and file name bit automatically.

```
="Daily Report\"&YEAR(A2)&"\"&TEXT(A2,"dd MMMyy")&"\["&TEXT(A2,"yymmdd")&" Daily Report.xls]Daily Report'!$A$1:$P$500,3,FALSE)*1"
```

[image]

The next issue is how you use that. You could plug that into an Indirect function, but if Indirect refers to an external file, that file must be open for Indirect to work. Which defeats the purpose.

So, the other option is that you build the complete formula as a text string,

```
="=VLOOKUP(""Oil Production(Sm³)"",'G:\DPNA\Non_Op_Assets\Hib\Pe\Production\Daily Report\"&YEAR(A2)&"\"&TEXT(A2,"dd MMMyy")&"\["&TEXT(A2,"yymmdd")&" Daily Report.xls]Daily Report'!$A$1:$P$500,3,FALSE)*1"
```

then copy and paste the formula as values, then edit each pasted cell and confirm the formula it now contains.

Edit: VBA is the way to go to bulk edit, but you won't be able to record this, since you will need a loop.

Comment: Thanks, that makes life a little easier. Is there a way to record a macro that can edit each pasted cell?

Answer (score 0):

Will the files be open? If so you can use `indirect` I just put a basic example together for you:

`=INDIRECT("'C:\Reporting Archive\[Daily Sales and Orders Report - 2018121" & ROW(A1)+5 & ".xlsx]Summary - Volume'!$C$41")`

I can drag this down and the `2018121` in the filename will start with a 6 then increment to a 7 then 8.

If you don't have the files open then you will need to use VBA. When reading from a closed workbook without opening it, I have always used the ExecuteExcel4Macro method like so:

```
strPath = "C:\Test\"
strFile = "Book1.xls"
strSheet = "Sheet1"
strRng = Range("A1")

strRef = "'" & strPath & "[" & strFile & "]" & strSheet & "'!" & strRng

Result = ExecuteExcel4Macro(strRef)
```